# How to make my sprite responsive

Tags: jquery, html, image, css, responsive-design

What we have is a set of blue curtains on a sprite which I want to make fluid as the background jpg gets reduced in width. 
Be aware that the blue curtains inside the sprite are covering the blue curtains of the jpg.
The sprite needs to cover the two blue curtains in the top center as the jpg is responsive.

See website: http://demo.chilipress.com/epic3/

The end result needs to look like this: [image]
And as you can see the there are three layers here. The jpg (which is the background), the curtains (the sprite) and the eagle (the sprite). So when changing the dimensions the sprite must remain on the correct position and act responsive.

HTML

```
<img src="assets/contact.jpg" alt="background image">
<div id="sprite_contact" class="sprite_contact"></div>
```

CSS

```
#sprite_contact{
max-width: 684px;
background: url('sprite_contact.png');}

.sprite_contact{
width: 100%;
height: 128px;
top: 0;
position: absolute;
margin: 0 0 0 27%;
background-size: cover;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to make my sprite fully responsive. For this I didn't use any slicing (photoshop) or javascript. Also notice how the sprites are positioned absolute and yet still responsive according the background.

For a better understanding of this process, please see the following link: http://brianjohnsondesign.com/unlisted/demos/responsivesprite/

Also see my link in order to see how it looks on my website: http://demo.chilipress.com/epic3/ Should my link not work anymore, try the first link above.

See here the CSS and HTML

```
#sprite1_contact{
background-image: url('sprite_contact.png');
width: 35.2%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 7%;
background-position: 0 0;
background-size: 100%;
display: block;
top: 0;
position: absolute;
margin: 0 0 0 32.3%;
z-index: 2;}

#sprite2_contact {
background-image: url('sprite_contact.png');
width: 27.5%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 28%;
background-position: 0 27%;
background-size: 100%;
display: block;
top: 0;
position: absolute;
margin: 0 0 0 35.8%;
z-index: 1;}
```

HTML

```
        <div id="sprite1_contact"></div>
        <div id="sprite2_contact"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you would be slicing each layers separately.

as from what I can see, we can slice it with the following:

a. wall - make it as your body background repeat (x and y)

[image]

b. floor - make this as background of a div, position it absolute, anchored to bottom and repeat-x, and center center position (z-index:1) and width 100%

[image]

c. curtains right - make this as background of a div, position it absolute, anchored to top and right (z-index:2)

[image]

d. curtains left -make this as background of a div, position it absolute, anchored to top and left (z-index:2)

[image]

e. curtains top - make this as background of a div, position it absolute, anchored to top and right and width 100% (z-index:3)

*** * This is just to illustrate. This is not sliced properly for I dont have PSD. ***

Comment: I believe there must be a way to resolve this simply with css and maybe some tweaking with html. 
But slicing it placing the parts like you are mentioning are probably unnecessary for something like this.

Comment: I dont think slicing would work very well with the lighting on the curtains.

Comment: yes you can use plain CSS.. ex: (1) make it as your `background-size: cover` but not all browsers/mobile could see that well for it is not compatible all around. (2) you can add `min-width` to that background `<img>` and adding your site wrapper with `overflow: hidden`, but this wont make it look center aligned (3) you can calculate it in jQuery on every browsers window's `.resize()` event to make is center..

Comment: lighting curtains can simply be done by extracting in your PSD the transparent glow effect.. make it as png.. like a lightglow layer.. (this is if your designer have not flatten the background and light glow)

Comment: In your first comment you are mentioning slicing the wall. I don't really understand what you mean by this  since there is a lightning effect in the center on the page and that the image is a background image in PS. 
The background image as it is now on the link I provided is flattend. 
I have cut out the curtains and duplicated them (which is a layer) and the eagles are separate layers. 

Also I have never sliced before in order to develop a website. 
So if there is absolutely no other way than to slice it, I'd rather not slice it.

Comment: I added pictures to illustrate more. They are just to illustrate thats why doesnt look sliced properly. If you really insist on just retaining the `<img>` as your background, might as well try to do my suggestion #2 #3 in my previous comment. And again `background-size: cover` should have been easy for this but it wont be compatible to all even on some mobile browsers. Also, if you make it as one big `<img/>` might as well considering to optimize your image because it is making your site load so slow.. else, you slice them separately.. :) well, its up to you though :)

Answer (score 0):

add following properties to your css:

```
#sprite_contact {
 max-width: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50% 0%;
 margin-left: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: No changes seem to happen. Is there anything else I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. http://zurb.com/playground/foundation-interchange
Really useful stuff. might help.